# FMDB - Passing Parameters for TEXT Data Types

Tags: sqlite, fmdb

I'm using FMDB to connect to my SqlLite database for an iOS Swift app.

My query is this for a text field (I changed the column names to simplify)

```
let externalQuery: FMResultSet = db.executeQuery("SELECT Field1, Field2 from MyTable where Field2 = ? ", 
withArgumentsIn: [someVariable])
```

Should the question mark have quotes around it if the column Field2 is of type TEXT in Sqllite?

For example should the query be this instead?

```
let externalQuery: FMResultSet = db.executeQuery("SELECT Field1, Field2 from MyTable where Field2 = '?' ", 
withArgumentsIn: [someVariable])
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No quotes are required, which should be easily confirmed with a quick test run.